# Excel VBA - Adding Hyperlink gets lost after data refresh

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I try to set hyperlinks via a macro after updating data from a SQL view.

When I run below macro it does set the hyperlink (temporarily) but once completed the hyperlinks are gone again.

If I run the sub that sets the hyperlinks on its own everything works so I believe it must be the data refresh that's causing the problem. To me it looks like the refresh is called again after setting the hyperlinks.

My code:

```
Sub loadData()

With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("myConnection").OLEDBConnection
    .CommandText = "EXEC [dbo].[View] '" & Parameter & "'"
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("myConnection").Refresh
End With

Call addHyperlink

' more code to follow....
Exit Sub
End Sub

Sub addHyperlink()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_Base")
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For i_count = 6 To LastRow
    If Worksheets("Data_Base").Range("B" & i_count).Value = "" Then
        Exit For
    Else
        Cells(i_count, 2).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(i_count, 2), _
         Address:="http://www." & Cells(i_count, 2).Value, _
         TextToDisplay:=Cells(i_count, 2).Value
    End If
Next i_count

End Sub
```

I've tried several ways to modify the properties of the data refresh but without luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems that the problem might be coming from `' more code to follow....`, so please add it! ;)

Comment: I already removed everything but the call to the addHyperlink sub. No luck. I belive it is the connection in the With part.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't think about this just now but indeed it must be your connection! In facts, it'll take some time to refresh and yet the code will continue instantly once the refresh order is given. So, add `DoEvents : Application.Wait(Now() + TimeValue("00:00:10")) : DoEvents` (3 lines) and your refresh must be finish after that and your hyperlinks will stay! ;)